# Go + Swig building with external lib

Tags: c++, go, swig, pkg-config

I'm trying to build a cpp file with opencv functions.

Go 1.3 states that swig building is now bundled in go build tool but I didn't find a way to tell that build tool to add include dirs and libs args with pkg-config.

```
go test -x cv_test.go                                                  
cd /Users/pierre/Projects/go-swig
clang++ -I . -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common -g -O2 -o $WORK/_/Users/pierre/Projects/go-swig/_obj/binding.cpp.o -c ./binding.cpp
# _/Users/pierre/Projects/go-swig
In file included from ./binding.cpp:1:
./binding.h:5:10: fatal error: 'cv.h' file not found
$WORK/command-line-arguments/_test/tiler.test
FAIL    command-line-arguments [build failed]
```

Has anyone did it successfully ?

Comment: Is it normal to have a space character between the -I and . at the beginning of the clang++ line?

Comment: It works if I run it manually with "-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/include/opencv -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/include"

I don't know what the -I . does, it has no effects when I remove it ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell CGo to use the include and link flags for a particular pkg-config library using the following syntax in one of your Go source files:

```
// #cgo pkg-config: some-package
import "C"
```

That is, include it along with any other declarations in the comment block processed by cgo.  It is only necessary to include this in one of the `.go` files in the package.  You can also specify additional compile and link flags:

```
// #cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++11
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/some/library/dir -lfoo
```

Full details can be found in [the cgo documentation](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)

Answer (score 6):

As of right now, Go doesn't correctly pass include paths to swig if you use pkg-config, I submitted a [patch](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8566) but it most likely won't be included until 1.4 is out.

So you either build Go with the patch or manually specify the paths with `#cgo CXXFLAGS / #cgo LDFLAGS` like @JamesHenstridge suggested.